# Compressing large 4D numpy arrays to HDF5 using h5py Killed: 9

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I am new to large datasets and having trouble extrapolating the explanations and tutorials I am reading to my problem.

I want to save 37019 images (450x600x3 each) to a numpy array and compress that into a file for training. Is it better to instantiate a 37019x450x600x3 array of zeros and modify them later or append 450x600x3 arrays one by one?

Right now I am using h5py but it results in a Killed: 9

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

imgarray = np.zeros((37019,450, 600, 3))

with h5py.File('deleteme.h5', 'a') as FOB:
    FOB.create_dataset("imgarray",data=imgarray,compression="gzip",compression_opts=9)
```

takes about 5 minutes, then:

```
Killed: 9
```

This does work when the number of images is smaller such as 3700 rather than 37019. 3700 results in a .h5 file that is 30MB.

Does this mean my array is too big for one dataset in h5dy? Do I need to save this in smaller chunks, separate datasets or something else altogether? whats method do you recommend for easy access and modification later?

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In you other question you found that there may be size limits for `zip` archives; it may also apply to `gzip` compression.  Or it may just be taking too long.

The `h5py` documentation indicates that a `dataset` is compressed on the fly when saved to an `h5py` file (and decompressed on the fly).  I also see some mention of it interacting with `chunking`.  You may have to explore the `h5py` github repository or the relevant mailing list.

Have you tried other compression methods or parameters?

How about saving your data in multiple datasets, each of a size that compresses easily?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way to do this, but I ended up just breaking my dataset into several numpy arrays each of size 1000x450x600x3 and gzip worked fine for this. It took 25 mins, but it all saved into a .h5 file 400MB in size. Thanks!